# [Nhibernate F]loading data to datagridview

Tags: c#, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I have a problems with retreving data correctly to datagridview. First what i got:

Two classes:

```
namespace hms.core.Entities
{
    public class Osoba : BaseEntity
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Imie { get; set; }
        public virtual decimal SumaWydatkow { get; set; }

        public virtual Dział Dział { get; set; } 
    }
}

namespace hms.core.Entities
{
    public class Dział
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Nazwa { get; set; }
        public virtual int SumaWydatkowDzialu { get; set; }

        public virtual IList<Osoba> Osoby { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And mappings:

```
namespace hms.data.Mappings
{
    public class OsobaMap : ClassMap<Osoba>
    {
        public OsobaMap()
        {
            Table("Osoba");

            Id(e => e.Id);
            Map(e => e.Imie, "Imie").Length(50);
            Map(e => e.SumaWydatkow, "SumaWydatkow");

            References(e => e.Dział, "IdDzialu").Not.LazyLoad();
        }
    }
}

namespace hms.data.Mappings
{
    public class DziałMapowanie : ClassMap<Dział>
    {
        public DziałMapowanie()
        {
            Table("Dział");

            Id(e => e.Id);
            Map(e => e.Nazwa, "Nazwa").Length(50);
            Map(e => e.SumaWydatkowDzialu, "SumaWydatkowDzialu");

            HasMany(c => c.Osoby).KeyColumn("IdDzialu").LazyLoad().Cascade.DeleteOrphan().Inverse();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to load data from table Osoba to datagridview, and it's ok, all information are viewing into database but only column "Dział" is showing me in all rows values:
hms.Core.Entities.Dział. How to solve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with WinForms, but it look like DataGridView does not know how to show your Dział object in columns so it just shows it ToString() representation. I think there should be a way to specify in Dział grid column which property of Dzial to show.